# Remove all character before the first dot

Tags: python

I have a column in an Excel sheet where I want to remove all characters before the first dot. For example: `columns1:{rj.23.456777,dg.344.56677,mn.334.333, and so on}`

I want to remove `rj,dg,mn`,

So that the output becomes `(23.456777,344.56677,334.333)`

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Do you want to do it in `python` or from `Excel` ? Please, have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python

```
s = "rj.23.456777"
s[s.find(".") + 1:]
```

or Excel formula (value is in cell A1)

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))
```

or Excel macro (you can loop throught your column):

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = Right(Cells(1, 1).Value, Len(Cells(1, 1).Value) - InStr(Cells(1, 1).Value, "."))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split function:

```
string.split(".",1)[-1]
```

This splits the string on the first "." and only does one split.  So the second part will be the substring you want.  If there are no "." in the string, the split will produce only one entry in the output array so we use [-1] to the the last entry rather than the second one.

for a list of strings you can do:

```
[ s.split(".")[-1] for s in listOfStrings ]
```